# Excel 2003 - How to count dates in row, including multiple dates in cell

Tags: excel

I have some data that looks like this:

[image]

However, I would like the total to exclude any text entries  (the formula should count dates only).  Because some boxes can have multiple dates in, I appreciate that those boxes will be counted as text.  Currently I am using this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:D2<>""),LEN(B2:D2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2:D2,",",""))+1)
```

Which counts the multiple dates in cells perfectly, but is also counting the text entries.  Thinking about it I could ask it to exclude instances which match 'Holiday' or 'Left'etc, but any pointers would be appreciated.

EDIT:  In the end I went with a compound (?) countif formula like this:

```
=COUNTIF(B3:D3,"Holiday")+COUNTIF(B3:D3,"Left")
```

and minused the total from the total yielded from the sumproduct.  Not an elegant solution, but it does work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as there's been no other suggestions, I will list this as the answer I went with.  Using something like:

```
=COUNTIF(B3:D3,"Holiday")+COUNTIF(B3:D3,"Left")
```

will help identify any specific entries I don't want to count in my total.  I can then use that to minus from the total achieved with the original formula.  Because my text entries come from a data validation list, this is a usable solution, but it's not ideal if you were looking to exclude any text entries (apart from multiple dates).

Answer (score 0):

did you try using COUNTIF with wildcards. Since your dates always contain a "/", you can try -

```
COUNTIF(A1:D1,"*/*")
```