# Force string variable to UK date format

Tags: excel, vba

I've a piece of VBA code that is available via www.contextures.com. It enables users to add multiple entries to a data validation list seperated by a comma. The user selects from a list of dates, and a list of text entries.

The user can free type a date, or use the pick list to select a date or text entry.  Sometimes two dates may need to go into a cell, so the VBA below allows the user to select/type one date, hit enter, then type another date in the same cell.  As soon as the user hits enter, the previous date appears in the cell, with the new date following separated by a comma.

This is the original piece of VBA.

```
Option Explicit
' Developed by Contextures Inc.
' www.contextures.com
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
  If Target.Column = 3 Then
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      Target.Value = oldVal _
        & ", " & newVal
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The problem is, when I enter a date in UK format into the cells the VBA applies to (such as 01/06/2013 i.e. dd/mm/yyyy), the VBA is intervening and returning the date as 06/01/2013 (mm/dd/yyyy).

My control panel settings are all UK format, so I figure it's something to do with how the VBA stores and then returns the date.  I tried making amendments to the dims oldval and newval (to dates) but then the VBA doesn't allow multiple entries in one cell as before.

I amended the VBA to a hacky workaround (below) which formats the dates to the non standard dd.mm.yyyy (dd/mm/yyyy doesn't work) but this would require me to tell users to input dates in this format which I'd rather not do (I'd rather allow the standard 01/01/2013 or 01-01-2013 both of which are recognised as dates by Excel):

```
Option Explicit
' Developed by Contextures Inc.
' www.contextures.com
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Format(Target.Value, "dd.mm.yyyy") 'amendment
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Format(Target.Value, "dd.mm.yyyy") 'amendment
  Target.Value = newVal
  If Target.Column > 1 Then 'amendment
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      Target.Value = oldVal _
        & ", " & newVal
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I'm using Excel 2007, but the spreadsheet needs to be compatible with 2003.

Edit:  The way the data looks is in this question here: [Excel 2003 - How to count dates in row, including multiple dates in cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299946/excel-2003-how-to-count-dates-in-row-including-multiple-dates-in-cell)

Edit: I should also mention that if I type 01/07/2013 into a cell twice, it comes out like this:

07/01/2013, 01/07/2013

It's like the first time the cell is populated it switches it to US date format, but anything after is ok.

Comment: No-repro. VBA uses the system settings in implicit conversions. Please check what display format is applied to the cells.

Comment: @GSerg: The format applied to the cells is Date>type *14/03/2001 with Locale set as English(U.K.). I've also tried 14/03/2001 but it makes no difference.  Going to try testing on a different machine to see if I get different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so after reading this article here: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html
I made some tweaks to the code:

```
 Option Explicit
' Developed by Contextures Inc.
' www.contextures.com
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  'newVal = Target.Value 'amendment
  newVal = Format(Target.Value, "\ dd\/mm\/yyyy\")

  Application.Undo
  'oldVal = Target.Value 'amendment
  oldVal = Format(Target.Value, "\ dd\/mm\/yyyy\")
  Target.Value = newVal
  If Target.Column > 1 Then 'amendment
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      Target.Value = oldVal _
        & ", " & newVal
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
```

exitHandler:
      Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub

The important bit appears to be the format:

```
oldVal = Format(Target.Value, "\ dd\/mm\/yyyy\")
```

Allen's suggested code was:

```
Format$(varDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
```

I changed it to dd/mm and replaced the # with a space, and hey presto - it appears to be working!  A very frustrating issue though, which I'll now have to make sure works on other users machines!  Thanks to @sous2817 and @GSerg for their comments/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me...unless I'm miss understanding your issue....

```
newVal = Format(Sheet1.Range("A1"), "dd/mm/yyyy;@")
```

Code in its entirety:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Format(Target.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy;@") 'amendment
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Format(Target.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy;@") 'amendment
  Target.Value = newVal
  If Target.Column > 1 Then 'amendment
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      Target.Value = oldVal _
        & ", " & newVal
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @sous2817, but using that, if I type a date into B2 it just disappears completed (Excel 2007)?  I've updated my question to try and make it a bit clearer about what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @bawpie:  I edited my post to include the entire method.  On my test sheet, it works exactly as you'd like it to. Enter a date in Column B:C and you get a comma delimited list of the dates that have been in that cell formatted to be more 'UK'friendly.

Comment: This is very bizarre. I've set up an entirely new workbook, put a list of dates in column k going from 01/01/2013 to 31/12/2013 and named it as 'List'. I've gone into data validation and applied it to column B, telling it to allow List, and setting the source as =list. The cell format is date, *14/03/2001, uk locale, and yet still when I select 01/07/2013 from the list, or free type it in, it reverts to 07/01/2013. I'm going to try this on my home pc tonight to see if it replicates. (This is using your posted code).  Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem - my VBA code wrote a cell value as string in UK format "DD/MM/YYYY" into a cell with local Date format set to DD/MM/YYYY but the date appeared in US format MM/DD/YYYY.

The above discussion was very helpful in identifying it as something VBA was doing rather than my code. To solve it I wrote a function to convert my UK date strings to US format date strings and wrote the US format date strings into the cell. VBA then processed the US dates into UK dates in the worksheet, which is what I wanted!

Public Function MM_DD_YYYY(DD_MM_YYYY As String) As String
'   Function switches date format from DD/MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY
Dim DD As String
Dim MM As String
Dim YYYY As String
DD = Left(DD_MM_YYYY, 2)
MM = Mid(DD_MM_YYYY, 4, 2)
YYYY = Right(DD_MM_YYYY, 4)
MM_DD_YYYY = MM & "/" & DD & "/" & YYYY
End Function

Answer (score -1):

Just this small change worked perfectly for me.

newVal = Format(Sheet1.Range("A1"), "**mm-dd**-yyyy;@")

My VBA was picking date as US format (mm-dd-yyyy). I wanted UK format (dd-mm-yyyy)

I just used the above code to read the value as US format itself, so VBA picks the date and month correctly. 
Ultimately, because my system settings are UK based, end result is UK format.